# Is it possible to replicate Android OS camera's passkey scan qr code capability in custom app?

Tags: android, qr-code, passkey, android-14

When I scan Passkey QR code via Android OS camera, I get a popup saying [Connect to QR code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgNeX.png) and then
[QR code scan process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBmrJ.png). This initiates BLE tunnel connection between Chrome and device(which is scanning QR code).

Is there a way to trigger this flow from a custom app? When I scan Passkey QR code value, I am able to decode it's CBOR value, but I am not able to find a way to trigger Android OS camera flow with the QR code information.

Is it even possible? Can only Android OS camera app do it? Any pointers or redirections would be appreciated?

I looked for functionality that lets you initiate a BLE connection using the same flow that Android OS camera uses.

Comment: As far as I know Google has extended support for Passkey provider apps in Android 14.

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating an app that can use passkeys for sign in (standard app), or a passkey provider (authenticator)?

Cross-Device Authentication uses a platform-implemented transport. You don't need to do anything in your app except call the credential manager APIs to request a sign in.

Comment: I am creating an passkey provider (authenticator) app. I researched in Credential Manager API, I didn't find method that accepts, passkey Scan QR code value. Scan QR content is in this String form: 

"FIDO:/455428845784270460731325821142275118867813002747898653223136146481532672045310149482030306647792515772590706253599935720073919752644225314037720051090178107096654083332"

I am not quite sure, on how to share this information (Its a CBOR value which is decodable) with credential Manager and it brings up the UI and takes care of rest of the process.

Any pointers?

Comment: Passkey providers don't implement CDA. It is handled by the platform. When you are installed and enabled as a passkey provider, requests from a CDA flow are delivered to your provider automatically by platform.

Recommend following the doc: https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/credential-provider

Comment: Thanks for sharing the resource. It seems like my app as a passkey provider, cannot implement CDA meaning even if I am able to scan the QR code and able to decode it, its not my app's job to call Credential Management API UI from within my App? Correct?

Comment: Correct, there is no need to. It is a platform service and everything will just work. You can, however, allow your app to scan a CDA QR code, but you would just intent off to the platform to handle it, just like the native camera app does.

Comment: Routing of CDA requests to CredMan providers is currently only enabled for a fraction of devices, but that fraction will be ramping up over the coming weeks.